# Creating a dynamic repeater with ng-content transclusion

Tags: angular, angular2-ngcontent

What I'm trying to achieve is a generic component that is bound to an array of arbitrary objects that allows adding and removing rows dynamically when the view of each row is also arbitrarily defined with components by a master component that uses it.

Note that `MasterComponent` is an arbitrary component that would be implemented for different pages and is intended to be self contained and not defined by any metadata or external source.

What I have so far are the following Components:

**RepeaterComponent template**:

```
<input type="button" value="Add" (click)="addRow()">
<div class="repeater" *ngFor="let row of repeaterArray">
    <div class="repeaterRow">
        <input type="button" value="Remove" (click)="removeRow(row.rowId)">
        <ng-content select="row"></ng-content>
     </div>
</div>
```

**MasterComponent template**:

```
<repeater [repeaterArray]="repeaterObj">
    <row>
        <field-textbox [data]="row.name" [label]="'Name'"></field-textbox>
        <field-textbox [data]="row.description" [label]="'Description'"></field-textbox>
    </row>
</repeater>
```

The `<field-textbox>` component is a custom component that I use to encapsulate simple inputs that holds some additional data that I need to use.

The **MasterComponent** holds an object that for this instance looks like this:

```
repeaterObj = [
{
    "rowId": 1,
    "name": "First brand",
    "description": "First description"
},
{
    "rowId": 2,
    "name": "Second brand",
    "description": "Second description"
},
{
    "rowId": 3,
    "name": "Third brand",
    "description": "Third description"
}
];
```

This approach has two issues that I can't seem to find a solution for.

1. The `ng-content` selector is identical for all the rows when the `ngFor` duplicates the template which leaves me with only one `ng-content` transclusion point after rendering.
2. There is no reference to the `row` variable from the `ngFor` declaration in the `<field-textbox>` transcluded directives so I can't bind the data correctly.

Is there a better approach to implement the `RepeaterComponent` that would give me the least amount of effort to create more new `MasterComponents` of different arbitrary structures and different templates?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You could use [ngTemplateOutlet](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgTemplateOutlet-directive.html) to achieve it.

Following are the steps in implementing dynamic repeater:

**First step** is to provide a `TemplateRef` as a child element of the `RepeaterComponent`:

```
<repeater [repeaterArray]="repeaterObj">
  <ng-template>
    ...
  </ng-template>
</repeater>
```

**Second step** is to query this template within `RepeaterComponent` via `@ContentChild`:

```
export class RepeaterComponent { 
  @ContentChild(TemplateRef) itemTemplate: TemplateRef<any>;
  ...
```

**Third step** is use `ngTemplateOutlet` to render the template:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'repeater',
  template: `
    <input type="button" value="Add" (click)="addRow()">
    <div class="repeater" *ngFor="let row of repeaterArray">
        <div class="repeaterRow">
            <input type="button" value="Remove" (click)="removeRow(row.rowId)">
            <ng-template <== this line
                    [ngTemplateOutlet]="itemTemplate"
                    [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{ $implicit: row }">
                </ng-template>
        </div>
    </div>`
})
export class RepeaterComponent { 
  @Input() repeaterArray: Array<any>;
  @ContentChild(TemplateRef) itemTemplate: TemplateRef<any>;
  ...
}
```

**Fourth step** is to use reference to the `row` inside `TemplateRef` within `MasterComponent` (just back to our first step):

```
<repeater [repeaterArray]="repeaterObj">
  <template let-row>
    <field-textbox [data]="row.name" [label]="'Name'"></field-textbox>
    <field-textbox [data]="row.description" [label]="'Description'"></field-textbox>
  </template>
</repeater>
```

Notice: we are passing `ngOutletContext` like object with `$implicit` property.

> using the key $implicit in the context object will set it's value as
>   default.

It works as follows:

```
[ngTemplateOutletContext]="{ $implicit: row }"  ==> <template let-row>

[ngTemplateOutletContext]="{ item: row }"       ==> <template let-row="item">
```

**`ngOutletContext` is availlable only since Angular 2 version of 2.0.0-rc.2**

You could try the corresponding [**plunkr**](https://plnkr.co/edit/VFEuqo0E89Azs8055390?p=preview) (updated to **5.0.0**)

Comment: Looks like this is exactly what I was looking for, thank you!

The only thing that seems to be not working as expected is the two-way binding on the field-textbox component with [(ngModel)].

The following [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/59vALT3ugZX1jIsMSOn6?p=preview) demonstrates the problem when you try to change the two different input fields with the same binding.

In the app component template you can see that the normal `<input>` binding works as intended and also updates the object bound but changing the <field-textbox> textbox does not apply the binding back to the object.

Comment: Try to use `EventEmitter` to achieve two-way binding like https://plnkr.co/edit/XpEDWD75bfnEtibKDKW7?p=preview

Comment: Yep, that works. I would expect the binding to propagate correctly without having to implement a two-way binding on the <field-textbox> component though seeing as the binding works when used outside of a template with [ngTemplateOutlet].

Comment: It's the same behavior like without ngTemplateOutlet https://plnkr.co/edit/ZP88WQsexq3UQpLTNriA?p=preview. ngTemplateOutlet doesn't make a magic. It is just pass data inside TemplateRef

Comment: Ah, you're right. I was thinking about binding to a defined class instance rather than to a JSON property. Thanks again!

Comment: on the fourth step, I think there's a small mistake and the tag should be "<ng-template let-row..." instead of "<template let-row..."