# angular2 (2.0.0) repeater using reactive forms and templates

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

**What I am trying to do:** I am building a reusable repeater of FormGroups (reactive forms) where the generic part of the repeater provides the add/remove controls and logic and all components that want to use it only have to provide the template that has to be repeated. I have checked

- [Creating a dynamic repeater with ng-content transclusion with angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38607075/creating-a-dynamic-repeater-with-ng-content-transclusion-with-angular2/38609725#38609725)

which shows how something like this can be done the *template driven way*.

**Where I am stuck:** the `formControlName` directive that I attach to the controls within the `<template>` is not picked up by the generic part of the repeater:

```
Error: Cannot find control with name: 'id'
at _throwError (https://unpkg.com/@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js:1527:15)
at setUpControl (https://unpkg.com/@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js:1465:13)
at FormGroupDirective.addControl (https://unpkg.com/@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js:3889:13)
at FormControlName._setUpControl (https://unpkg.com/@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js:4318:48)
at FormControlName.ngOnChanges (https://unpkg.com/@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js:4264:22)
```

**Code:** ([plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/BXjXJuz4lqMB8O5OXNGc?p=preview))

*RepeaterComponent2*

```
@Component({
    selector: 'repeater2',
    template: `
        <div *ngIf="formArray">debug formArray: {{formArray.length}}</div>
        <div [formGroup]="formGroup">
            <input type="button" value="add" (click)="addRow()" noBootstrap>
            <div formArrayName="values" class="repeater" *ngFor="let row of model; let i = index">
                <div [formGroupName]="i" class="repeaterRow">
                    <input type="button" value="remove" (click)="removeRow(row, i)"  noBootstrap>
                    <template [ngTemplateOutlet]="itemTemplate" [ngOutletContext]="{item: row}"></template>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    `
})
export class RepeaterComponent2 implements OnInit {
    /* initial model */
    @Input() model: any[] = [];
    /* function to create a new item */
    @Input() newItem: (i) => {};
    /* function to create a new FormGroup to fit the item */
    @Input() newItemFormGroup: (fb: FormBuilder, model: any) => FormGroup;
    /* root form group where the local FormArray is attached to */
    @Input() formGroup: FormGroup;    

    @Output() repeaterArrayChanged: EventEmitter<any[]>;
    @ContentChild(TemplateRef) itemTemplate: TemplateRef<any>;    

    formArray: FormArray;    

    constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
        this.repeaterArrayChanged = new EventEmitter<any[]>();
    }    

    ngOnInit() {
        this.formArray = this.fb.array([]);
        this.formGroup.addControl('values', this.formArray);
        this.model.forEach((item: any) => this.addItemFormGroup(item))
    }    

    addRow() {
        let id = this.model.length + 1;
        let obj = this.newItem(id);
        this.model.push(obj);
        this.addItemFormGroup(obj);
        this.repeaterArrayChanged.emit(this.model);
    }    

    addItemFormGroup(item: any) {
        this.formArray.push(this.newItemFormGroup(this.fb, item));
    }    

    removeItemFormGroup(i) {
        this.formArray.removeAt(i);
    }    

    removeRow(row, i) {
        this.model = this.model.filter((x: any) => x !==row);
        this.removeItemFormGroup(i);
        this.repeaterArrayChanged.emit(this.model);
    }
}
```

*How it should be used:*

```
    @Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
        <div>
            <div>{{debugForm | json}}</div>
            <form [formGroup]="formGroup">
                <!-- passing in:
                    - the root form group (the formArray of the repeater adds itself to it)
                    - the initial model items
                    - a callback that is used to create a new model item when "add" is clicked 
                    - a callback that is used to create a "suitable" FormGroup for the passed model item 
                -->
                <repeater2 [formGroup]="formGroup" [model]="model.items" [newItem]="newItem" [newItemFormGroup]="newItemFormGroup">
                    <template let-row="item">
                        <span>{{row | json}}</span>
                        <!-- !!! THIS FORM CONTROL IS NOT PICKED UP !!! -->
                        <input type="text" formControlName="id" noBootstrap>
                    </template>
                </repeater2>
            </form>
        </div>
    `
})
export class RepeaterTestComponent2 implements OnInit {    

    model: Model;
    formGroup: FormGroup;    

    constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
        this.model = new Model(1, [
            new Item(1, 'one'),
            new Item(2, 'two'),
            new Item(3, 'three')
        ]);
    }    

    ngOnInit() {
        this.formGroup = this.fb.group({});
    }    

    newItem(i): any {
        return new Item(i, 'xxx');
    }    

    newItemFormGroup(fb: FormBuilder, model: any): any {
        return fb.group({
            id: []
        });
    }    

    get debugForm() {
        return {
            value: this.formGroup.value
        };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this is possible as per a similar question linked below.

Basically, your element must implement the `ControlValueAccessor` interface which `ngModel` and `formControlName` inject, like so:

```
@Directive({
  selector: 'control',
  providers: [
    {provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR, multi: true, useExisting: SwitchControlComponent}
  ]
})
export class SwitchControlComponent implements ControlValueAccessor {
  isOn: boolean;
  _onChange: (value: any) => void;

  writeValue(value: any) {
    this.isOn = !!value;
  }

  registerOnChange(fn: (value: any) => void) {
    this._onChange = fn;
  }

  registerOnTouched() {}

  toggle(isOn: boolean) {
    this.isOn = isOn;
    this._onChange(isOn);
  }
}
```

Be aware that you must (AFAIK) then though pass the form to the transcluded template— see `let-form="form"`

```
<repeater2 [formGroup]="formGroup" [model]="model.items" [newItem]="newItem" [newItemFormGroup]="newItemFormGroup">
    <template let-row="item" let-form="form">
        <span>{{row | json}}</span>
        <input control type="text" formControlName="id" noBootstrap>
    </template>
</repeater2>
```

Further reading:

[Angular2: Bind form context to ngTemplateOutlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40536901/angular2-bind-form-context-to-ngtemplateoutlet/41215963#41215963)

[With new forms api, can't add inputs from child components without adding additional form tags](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/9281)