# Angular2 - How to make a input added by ngTemplateOutlet recognised by the FormGroup?

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-forms, angular4-forms

I have the following template

```
<template #myTemplate >
  <input type="text" class="input-sm" required />    
</template>
```

I refer this template to formGroup, like this

```
<div [formGroup]="testForm">
  <div [ngTemplateOutlet]="myTemplate" [ngOutletContext]="{item: item}">
</div>
```

This template `#myTemplate` is provided by the end user of the component.

The problem here is, it is not getting recognised by the formGroup and hence not able to validate. On googling I found we need to register this control with NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR. So added a attribute directive to the input element.

```
@Directive({ 
selector: '[control]',
providers: [
{ 
  provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR, multi: true, 
  useExisting: forwardRef(() => TempControl),
}],
host: {'(change)': 'onChange($event.target.value)', '(blur)':
'onTouched()'},
})
export class TempControl implements ControlValueAccessor{
  onChange = (_) => {};
  onTouched = () => {} 
  constructor(private renderer: Renderer2, private elem: ElementRef) {
  }
  writeValue(value) : void {
    this.renderer.setProperty(this.elem.nativeElement, 'value', value);
  } 
  registerOnChange(fn: (_: any) => void): void {
    this.onChange = fn;
  }
  registerOnTouched(fn){ this.onTouched = fn; }
}
```

And I have added this directive to the input element, like below

```
<template #myTemplate >
  <input type="text" class="input-sm" control required />    
</template>
```

But the element is not recognised by the form group even after registering it with `NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR` and implementing `ControlValueAccessor`.

I understand templateref is not moved inside the formGroup, only a reference is made available there and hence the formGroup is not able to detect the input. What is the right solution in this case?

I referred this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40536901/angular2-bind-form-context-to-ngtemplateoutlet), Does just implementing the `ControlValueAccessor` makes the enclosing formGroup aware of this new input? After doing this I checked `FormGroup.controls` which doesn't have this new input.

I have reproduced the problem in this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngtemplate-validation)

Comment: Where is the name of your control?

Comment: Name means? it is an input control. It is inside `#myTemplate` @yurzui

Comment: Each control in FormGroup should have name

Comment: @yurzui Thanks for the comment. Yes it should have a name. But I am having this template in another component and I can't simply added formControlName to the component there, because it throws an error. How to add formControlName to the input, because it will be part of the formGroup only after being referred by the ngTemplateOutlet
?

Comment: Where does template come from? ContentChild? Can you create an example on stackblitz?

Comment: @yurzui - Yes, the template comes from the content child. Will try to create one stackblitz.

Comment: Any progress on this?

Comment: @yurzui - https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngtemplate-validation , Reproduced the problem in stackblitz. I need to validate those two text boxes. It is not recognised by formGroup.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngtemplate-validation-vgs6qf?file=app/cust.component.ts