# Angular4+ content projection unclear

Tags: angular

I would like to create a list of styled elements based on an item template and a list of items coming from json in Angular4. My code at the moment is as follows:

```js
@Directive({selector: '[mnItem]'})
export class MnItemDef {
  constructor(private _viewContainer: ViewContainerRef, private templateRef: TemplateRef<any>) { }
  @Input() mnItem : any;

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.mnItem);
    this._viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef, {$implicit:this.mnItem});
  }
}


@Component({
  selector: 'mn-element',
  template:'<div [fxFlex]="itemWidth" *mnItem="let item"><ng-container></ng-container></div>'
})
export class MnElementDef {
  @Input() itemWidth;
  @Input() item;

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit(){
    console.log(this.item);
  }
}


@Component({
  selector: 'mn-flex-cards',
  templateUrl: './mn-flex-cards.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./mn-flex-cards.component.css']
})
export class MnFlexCardsComponent implements OnInit {

  @ViewChild('placeHolder', {read: ViewContainerRef}) private _placeHolder: ViewContainerRef;

  @Input() items = [];


  constructor(private _cmpFctryRslvr: ComponentFactoryResolver) { 
  }

  doGetPage(){
    if (this.mode == "memory"){
      this.items = this.filtered.slice(this.pageSize*this.pageIndex,this.pageSize*(this.pageIndex+1) )
    }

    for (let itm of this.items){
      let cmp = this.createComponent(this._placeHolder, MnElementDef);
      cmp.instance.itemWidth = this.itemWidth;
      cmp.instance.item = itm;
      this._placeHolder.insert(cmp.hostView);
    }
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    if(this.mode == "memory"){
      this.itemSize = this.memoryItems.length;
      this.filtered = this.memoryItems.slice(0,this.memoryItems.length);
    }
    this.doGetPage();
  }
}
```

The templates

```
<div fxLayout='row' class="zero" fxLayoutAlign="space-around center" fxLayoutWrap fxLayoutAlign="center stretch">
  <ng-template #placeHolder></ng-template>
</div>
```

and the using element:

```
<mn-flex-cards 
    [memoryItems]="items" 
    mode="memory" 
    [filter]="false" 
    [pager_bottom]="false" 
    backend="bms">
      <mn-element>
        <div style="margin:10px;"  *mnItem="let item">
          <md-card class="filo-card" >
            <md-card-header>
              <md-card-title><span class="title">{{item.title}}</span></md-card-title>
              <md-card-subtitle><span class="subtitle">{{item.subtitle}}</span></md-card-subtitle>
            </md-card-header>

            <md-card-content>
              <div style="width:10%; float:left;">
                <img src="{{item.img}}">
              </div>
              <div style="width:90%; float:right; text-align:right;">
                <p class="descr" [innerHtml]="item.descr"></p>
              </div>
              <div style="clear:both;"></div>
            </md-card-content>
          </md-card>
        </div>
    </mn-element>
</mn-flex-cards>
```

For some reason the result is always

PagesPointsComponent.html:24 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of null
    at Object.eval [as updateRenderer] (PagesPointsComponent.html:24)
    at Object.debugUpdateRenderer [as updateRenderer] (vendor.bundle.js:sourcemap:70245)
    at checkAndUpdateView (vendor.bundle.js:sourcemap:69392)
    at callViewAction (vendor.bundle.js:sourcemap:69752)
    at execEmbeddedViewsAction (vendor.bundle.js:sourcemap:69710)
    at checkAndUpdateView (vendor.bundle.js:sourcemap:69388)
    at callViewAction (vendor.bundle.js:sourcemap:69752)
    at execComponentViewsAction (vendor.bundle.js:sourcemap:69684)
    at checkAndUpdateView (vendor.bundle.js:sourcemap:69393)
    at callViewAction (vendor.bundle.js:sourcemap:69752)

https://embed.plnkr.co/jJuGEhYvxIlGl5utSsYF/

Comment: Can you create a plunker?

Comment: most of the libraries used are not documented with systemjs. I will have to try some tweaks...

Comment: You do not need all libraries

Comment: I pruned all libraries not used, yet I get a "No provider for ApplicationRef!" error...

Comment: Here's your plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/M1IFVD3uA9BwWPpnoQ0m?p=preview But i don't understand how you are expecting it working. At least here should be `ng-content` or `@ContentChild` for `TemplateRef`

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38607075/creating-a-dynamic-repeater-with-ng-content-transclusion-with-angular2/38609725#38609725 or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39561688/nested-templates-in-angular-2/39562120#39562120

Comment: thank you so much!!